# Changing text color clears TextInput in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have tried getting the result in a couple of different ways but i don't know if this is a bug or if i am doing something wrong.

When ****changing the color** in styling** of my TextInput the **input gets cleared** and all text goes away **showing only placeholder text**.

```
const [focusInputTextColor, setFocusInputTextColor] = useState("000000");

const onFocusInput = () => {
    setFocusInputTextColor('#ffffff');
};

const onBlurInput = () => {
    setFocusInputTextColor('#000000');
};

<TextInput
    style={[styles.input,{color:focusInputTextColor}]}
    onChangeText={() => console.log("test")}
    placeholder="Placeholder here"
    placeholderTextColor="#000000"
    onFocus={() => onFocusInput()}
    onBlur={() => onBlurInput()}
/>
```

Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: what is `<TextInput />`? What library does it come from? Does it implement [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)/[uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is likely due to the way you're handling the `onChangeText` event. The `onChangeText` event is called every time the text in the `TextInput` changes, but you're not updating the state with the new text. To fix this issue, try updating the state with the new text in the `onChangeText` event.

---

**Edit - Q1:**
It could be because the `onBlur` event is being triggered before the `onChangeText` event. You can try updating the state with the input text in the `onBlur` event to see if that fixes the issue.

Here is an example:

```js
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
const [focusInputTextColor, setFocusInputTextColor] = useState("000000");

const onFocusInput = () => {
setFocusInputTextColor('#ffffff');
};

const onBlurInput = () => {
setFocusInputTextColor('#000000');
setInputText(inputText);
};

<TextInput
style={[styles.input,{color:focusInputTextColor}]}
onChangeText={text => setInputText(text)}
value={inputText}
placeholder="Placeholder here"
placeholderTextColor="#000000"
onFocus={() => onFocusInput()}
onBlur={() => onBlurInput()}
/>
```

Comment: That was my first thought but i added a simple console.log in the onChangeText event which dont get called when onBlurInput() gets called.

Comment: Edit - Q1 solved it! Seems strange though but i am happy with the result :D Thank you alot!